# How to kill a list of processes in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, process, kill

I am new to C# and am trying to kill a list of processes. I was able to use the code below to kill one process but would like to change it so that it kills a list of processes. Over time the list will grow so ideally I would like to find a way to do this where updating the list would be quick and easy.

```
try
{
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"))
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Procces not found.");
}
```

I'm sorry if I have overlooked a question that was already asked about this.
Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: You should store the name of the processes you want to kill in a separate data structure. I recommend checking out the documentation for classes in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObservableCollection<T>` class provides an event if the collection is changed. So you can create a collection of `Process` and handle new added items in the event handler:

```
ObservableCollection<Process> processes = new ObservableCollection<Process>();
processes.CollectionChanged += processes_CollectionChanged;

static void processes_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
        foreach (var process in e.NewItems.OfType<Process>())
            process.Kill();
    processes.Clear();//remove all Processes from the list
}
```

But it is not really worth to do it in this way. I think it is more easier to call your code every time you want to kill a process.

The way with the collection is only worthwhile if you change the generic argument to `string` or `int` and pass the process name or pid. In this cases, you can determine the `Process` object in the `CollectionChanged` event handler and kill them there. (Like in your code.)